# Scrapy returning 403 error (Forbidden)

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, http-status-code-403

I'm very new to Scrapy as well as to using Python. In the past, I have managed to get a minimal example of Scrapy working but haven't used it since.
Meanwhile, a new version is out (I think the one I used last time was `0.24`) and I can't, for the life of me, figure out why I'm getting a 403 error no matter what website I attempt to crawl.

Granted, I have yet to delve into Middlewares and/or Pipelines but I was hoping to be able to get a minimal example running before exploring any further. That being said, here's my current code:

## items.py

```
import scrapy

class StackItem(scrapy.Item):
   title = scrapy.Field()
   url = scrapy.Field()
```

## stack_spider.py

```
#derived from https://realpython.com/blog/python/web-scraping-with-scrapy-and-mongodb/
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from stack.items import StackItem

class StackSpider(Spider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [403, 404] #kind of out of desperation. Is it serving any purpose?
    name = "stack"
    allowed_domains = ["stackoverflow.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=newest",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        questions = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="summary"]/h3')

        for question in questions:
            self.log(question)
            item = StackItem()
            item['title'] = question.xpath('a[@class="question-hyperlink"]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['url'] = question.xpath('a[@class="question-hyperlink"]/@href').extract()[0]
            yield item
```

## Output

```
(pyplayground) 22:39 ~/stack $ scrapy crawl stack                                                                                                                             
2016-03-07 22:39:38 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.5 started (bot: stack)                                                                                                          
2016-03-07 22:39:38 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11                                                                                                   
2016-03-07 22:39:38 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'stack.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['stack.spiders'], 'RETRY_TIMES': 5, 'BOT_NAME': 'stack', 'RET
RY_HTTP_CODES': [500, 502, 503, 504, 400, 403, 404, 408], 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3}                                                                                                
2016-03-07 22:39:39 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState                                                           
2016-03-07 22:39:39 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddlewa
re, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpProxyMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats                  
2016-03-07 22:39:39 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware                
2016-03-07 22:39:39 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:                                                                                                                    
2016-03-07 22:39:39 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened                                                                                                                              
2016-03-07 22:39:39 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)                                                                         
2016-03-07 22:39:39 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023                                                                                                
2016-03-07 22:39:39 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=newest> (failed 1 times): 403 Forbidden                                 
2016-03-07 22:39:42 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=newest> (failed 2 times): 403 Forbidden                                 
2016-03-07 22:39:47 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=newest> (failed 3 times): 403 Forbidden                                 
2016-03-07 22:39:51 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=newest> (failed 4 times): 403 Forbidden                                 
2016-03-07 22:39:55 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=newest> (failed 5 times): 403 Forbidden                                 
2016-03-07 22:39:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=newest> (failed 6 times): 403 Forbidden                         
2016-03-07 22:39:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET http://stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=newest> (referer: None)                                            
2016-03-07 22:39:58 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)                                                                                                                  
2016-03-07 22:39:58 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:                                                                                                                      
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1488,                                                                                                                                            
 'downloader/request_count': 6,                                                                                                                                               
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 6,                                                                                                                                    
 'downloader/response_bytes': 6624,                                                                                                                                           
 'downloader/response_count': 6,                                                                                                                                              
 'downloader/response_status_count/403': 6,                                                                                                                                   
 'finish_reason': 'finished',                                                                                                                                                 
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 7, 22, 39, 58, 458578),                                                                                                            
 'log_count/DEBUG': 8,                                                                                                                                                        
 'log_count/INFO': 7,                                                                                                                                                         
 'response_received_count': 1,                                                                                                                                                
 'scheduler/dequeued': 6,                                                                                                                                                     
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 6,                                                                                                                                              
 'scheduler/enqueued': 6,                                                                                                                                                     
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 6,                                                                                                                                              
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 7, 22, 39, 39, 607472)}                                                                                                             
2016-03-07 22:39:58 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: what version are you  using and is it just on SO you are having issues?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Forgot to mention that. I'm using Scrapy `1.0.5` on Ubuntu (`Linux  3.13.0-76-generic #120-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 15:59:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`)

Comment: Try adding a user agent in your settings file. Something like `USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.36 Safari/535.7'`

Comment: No luck yet. I tried both your string and a variation (`USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36"`). It's still throwing a 403 error.

Comment: What does `scrapy shell` give you for that URL? Do you get the same for `https://stackoverflow....`? Here's a Scrapy 1.0.5 shell session output when I run it locally: https://gist.github.com/redapple/ada965243a5c187e41a1 . Can you run the same and share your logs?

Comment: Sure thing, [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dc2afef6eb459a816e0c) it is.

Comment: What about request headers and  response headers? does it give you the same when using the https:// version?

Comment: There wasn't anything wrong with the code, see below for details. Thank you for the help, everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most definitely you are behind a proxy. Check and set appropriately your `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` environment variables. Cross check with `curl` if you can get that URL from the terminal.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. As it turns out, I was working on a remote environment and completely forgot about that detail. Trying cURL was what I should have done in the first place.